# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the demo code on Tensorflow CNN's, and I've ran into this error involving logging_hook

> File "Machine_Learning/CNN_model_creator.py", line 105, in main
>       hooks=[logging_hook]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    #create the estimator
clf = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/model")

#set up logging for predictions
#log the values in the "softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities":"softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

#train the model_f
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": train_data},
    y=train_labels,
    batch_size=100,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True
)
clf.train(
    input_fn=train_input_fn,
    steps=20000,
    hooks=[logging_hook]
)
```

I don't fully understand the purpose of logging_hook, or why it needs to be in a list when its value is passed to hooks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: according to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator):
_"hooks: List of SessionRunHook subclass instances. Used for callbacks inside the training loop."_ so it must be a list of hooks

Comment: I understand that, but there still seems to be a problem, where its throwing the error in the title of this question.

Comment: should it be tensors_to_log = {"probabilities":softmax_tensor} instead? Don't tell me you're passing the string "softmax_tensor" as the value of the Tensor, which might be interpreted as list and cause the error. This is an example which worked for me:  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss": loss,
                                               "accuracy": accuracy[0], "auc": auc[0]}, every_n_iter=params['skip_step'])